# What is the good practice of learning LaTeX for a CSE student?

Tags: best-practices, books, learning, vim-latex

A CSE student has knowledge about some programming language. So, learning LaTeX is not so hard for him. And he also familiar about some indentation and syntax of different language.

Now , what is the starting point and practice for a CSE student for leaning LaTeX completely.

In addition  , if he uses a Linux as OS and  vim as text editor.

Comment: The backround doesn't matter. Reading an introduction is the way to start.

Comment: I don't believe the specific points in this question (CSE, Linux, vim) make much of a difference.  Generally beginner resources assume some (minimal) understanding of the concept of writing code and familiarity with your chosen editor and OS.  A good CSE student should have a slight headstart but that's all

Comment: Beside to read some introducción, my suggestion is learn with minimal examples: make  simple documents with  Lyx  (for example, a few words, an enumerated list with a few items, 2 2x2 table, etc.), and try to understand the generated  LaTeX  source. And, of course, experiment with the thousands of minimal working examples in this site.